# Can a chrome extension can limit bandwidth of certain urls?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

can we made a chrome extension that can limit bandwidth to certain URLS or (bandwidth limit to all URLS except few)
What Technologies do we know to implement this?

Comment: Not really. The closest you can get is [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) + [emulateNetworkConditions](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions). Don't ask me.

Comment: You and [Josiah Tullis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7697469/josiah-tullis) appear to be working on the same project/in the same class. You have both asked [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744575) of a variety that doesn't really fit the Stack  Overflow format. Please, coordinate between whatever group of people is working working on this so that multiple, very similar questions are not posted. Please also read  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask] and [mcve].