# Is there a way to create custom network throttling profiles from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I know that Chrome now supports network throttling form the Network tab of DevTools, but I want to create a Chrome extension that either does this itself or utilizes the existing DevTool to create a custom throttling speed. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Just guessing: [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API + [emulateNetworkConditions](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/tot/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions).

Comment: You and [Ravi Raj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6810629/ravi-raj)  appear to be working on the same project/in the same class. You have both asked [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744568/can-a-chrome-extension-can-limit-bandwidth-of-certain-urls) of a variety that doesn't really fit the Stack  Overflow format. Please, coordinate between whatever group of people is working working on this so that multiple, very similar questions are not posted. Please also read  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask] and [mcve].